# How to securely store database connection details

Tags: database, security

In an application that needs to open a database connection, the username/password details must be sent to the database. What is the most secure way of storing, and using, this data?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. Web/C#/Java etc .... ?

Comment: Hi Deviant. I'm trying to keep the question general, because I believe it's a general issue. If everyone thinks otherwise, though, I'll add a bit more detail - it IS regarding web apps.

Comment: Who are you defending against? What is your distribution? Is this a client application talking to a central DB? Is this a web application?
What language and which DB are you using? Giving a bit more detail will get you much more specific answers.

Comment: It's not a general question unfortunately

Comment: I'm not sure - I think '1800 information's answer is a good, general response - is there some way that advice would vary depending on specific conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact method depends on the environment, but in general, you store the credentials in a location which is only readable by the user that your application is running as. For example on Windows you would store the credentials in the registry in a location protected by an ACL so that only that user could read it. Optionally, you could use the DPAPI to encrypt the data so it was further protected. In Unix, you would store it in a file that was protected with `chmod` (and optionally encrypted) so that only the app could read it.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the database you're using. For Microsoft SQL Server you either encrypt the database connection string in the configuration or you use integrated security, where you connect to the database using the identity of the application you're connecting from.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent question.
It's an issue with which we've grappled - and come up with a variety of approaches.

The first answer is to go with 1800 INFORMATION's suggestion:

#### put it in an area only readable by the userid running your application.

I don't think you'll get a better all-round solution than this.

Other methods we've toyed with (and rejected):

- Save it in an encrypted file

  - this only works if the attacker can't get to your code to see how the encryption works, so not so good most of the time.
- Save it in the database and require a human to log on to start the application

  - this works, as long as you are in a position to have a real person start up the application all the time
- Rely on built-in security devices, such as those in .NET (see rwwilden's answer).

  - this is a good solution if you are, e.g. a Microsoft shop.

Answer (score 0):

not in your source code but instead in a separate file read by your application. then use system security to make this file only readable by the application user