# Save database connection details

Tags: php, mysql, database, ini

I'm creating a setup script for a project, where a form would ask the user for database connection details (such as host, username and password), and it should store these in a file which the main system can use in the future.

How could this be accomplished - by generating an .ini file, or by using PHP to edit another PHP file?

Comment: I'm sure one script *can* write another, but likely safer to put it on a reservation in another folder in a restricted file you read or include knowing it may be corrupt.

Comment: The format is up to you (Laravel stores configuration options into an array, you could store it as a JSON object). To securely read/write it, you might want to think about the answers given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/824055/899126)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This [link](http://davidwalsh.name/basic-php-file-handling-create-open-read-write-append-close-delete)

```
     $my_file = 'db.ini';
        $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
/*Writing*/
        $data = 'This is the data';
        fwrite($handle, $data);
/*Reading*/
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'r');
$data = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));
```